# Why does the value that DI is pointing to change when I changed the value that SI is pointing to?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
push si
push [bx]
mov si, [si]
mov [bx], si 
mov di, bx
pop bx
pop si
mov [si], bx
```

This is my code. For some reason the value that di is pointing to changes after mov[si], bx (the last line).
Does anybody know why?

Edit: Both si and di are pointing to values in the same array, which is defined as db. The value that di is pointing to becomes the value after it in the array.

Comment: Maybe `si` and `di` point to the same memory address?

Comment: No, they don't.

Comment: You probably have a byte array but you are writing words so affecting two elements at a time.

Comment: Huh, you're right! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jester was correct, I added words to an array of bytes which changed not only the specific part I was trying to change but also the parts around it.

Comment: Upvote for answering your own question!  Always nice to see that.